# Fit a poisson normalised distribution in a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to plot a normalised poisson distribution with the same average as this list:

```
merged_back = [2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4,
       9, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3,
       3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3,
       6, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 2, 3, 1, 1,
       3, 4, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 6, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 3,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

i.e with the following average:

```
back_avg = np.average(merged_back) = 2.55
```

I want it to fit the following histogram:

[image]

I tried this code but as you can see It's not working!

```
plt.hist(merged_back, bins= 4,color="red")
rng = np.random.default_rng()
poisson = rng.poisson(lam=back_avg, size=140)
plt.plot(decay_back_1 ,  poisson)
plt.show()
```

Any tips?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Also your last code block references `decay_back_1` that is not defined in your snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

merged_back = [2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4,
               9, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3,
               3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3,
               6, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 2, 3, 1, 1,
               3, 4, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 6, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 3,
               0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

back_avg = np.average(merged_back)

plt.hist(merged_back, bins=4, color="red", alpha=0.5, density=True, label='Histogram')

poisson = np.random.poisson(lam=back_avg, size=100000)

plt.hist(poisson, bins=4, color="blue", alpha=0.5, density=True, label='Poisson Distribution')

plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Normalized Frequency')
plt.title('Histogram with Poisson Distribution')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which gives you

[image]